# Maven и Gradle как собирать и как создать проект? Java и IDEA

Tags: java, maven

Всем привет!
Плохо понимаю как собирать проекты. Знаю что этим занимаюся Maven, Gradle,Ant.

Но нужно разбирать во всем или выбрать один инструмент и разбираться в нем?

Также если я создам например MAven проект в IDEA, то я получу обычный Java проект с поддержкой Maven или это какой-то особенный проект?

А что если у меня уже написан какой-то проект как к нему подключить Сборщик? 
Если я хочу развиваться в сторону Android  какой сборщик стоит учить?

Прочитал кучу статей про них, все философские, нет конкретных гайдов что делать и как с ними работать.

Comment: «Если я хочу развиваться в сторону Android какой сборщик стоит учить?» – `Gradle`.

Comment: Создайте в корне проекта файл pom.xml и добавьте в него минимальную конфигурацию. https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Quick_Overview
```
<groupId>...</groupId>
<artifactId>...</artifactId>
<version>...</version>
<packaging>...</packaging>
```
IDEA должна его заметить и предложить добавить maven модуль в проект.
Код по умолчанию должен находится в `/src/main/java/{groupId.artifactId}`

Answer (score 2):

Консервативным выбором считается Maven – в любом случае не прогадаете, если начнете с него. К тому же, неплохо иметь представление о том как работает Maven, прежде чем начинать знакомится с Gradle (как сначала освоить фортепиано, прежде чем учиться играть на гитаре).

Все, что нужно знать про Maven:
     - maven goals and phases
     - mvn archetype:generate
     - pom.xml и управление зависимостями
     - mvn clean install
     - ...
     - PROFIT

Про Gradle все, что нужно знать, так это то, что билд скрипты полностью кастомизируемы и пишутся на groovy.

Comment: Понимаете в чем проблема, я например создаю, Maven проект и там создается обычный чистый Java проект + файлы мавена и самое важно что я могу создавать java классы. Но если я создаю Gradle проект, то там ничего нет кроме пару  файлов Gradle и я в созданном проекте не могу создавать Java  классы.  И я не могу понять почему так происходит и что я делаю не так. 

Также я не понимаю как подключать сборщики если проект уже создан без них?

Comment: Или как например одновременно создать Spring проект и Maven проект?

Comment: @AlexKing Начну с последнего вопроса: насколько я знаю, Spring проект можно либо выбрать среди артефактов Maven, либо создать generic application и просто добавить в pom.xml Spring dependency.

Gradle я особо не щупал, надо будет поиграться на досуге. Причина, по которой я этого еще не сделал – стараюсь избегать излишней сложности / кастомизируемости. Ведь главное – get things done, а не создавать из build tool вещь в себе. По теме:   

https://twitter.com/id_aa_carmack/status/774024499532472322   

https://twitter.com/ID_AA_Carmack/status/656956280888672256